# Setting charset on thermal printer via ESC/POS

Tags: printing, character-encoding, bluetooth-lowenergy, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer "MPT-II" from an unknown Chinese brand, that has both USB and Bluetooth. I can successfully print text using:

1. Loyverse app on Android
2. JavaScript
3. Raw HEX or decimal

However, only using the Loyverse app am I able to input special characters, and by special characters I mean the Danish characters æøå/ÆØÅ.

If I open up any BLE tool on Windows (Bluetooth LE Lab for example), I can select the correct characteristic and send something like `104 101 108 108 111 13 10` which would print "hello" on the printer. I've read a bit about the `ESC R` and `ESC t` commands, but how exactly do I set those modes? I've tried prepending it to each command, such as `27 82 1 104 101 108 108 111 13 10` where the `27 82 1` corresponds to `ESC R 4` and the `4` corresponds to `Denmark I`.

According to the printer's manual, it states the following:

> GB18030 character set, ASCII characters, user defined characters, bar codes CODE39, EAN13, EAN8, CODABAR, CODE93, ITF, bitmaps.

According to that list, the Danish character set is not supported. I'm not sure how the Loyverse app is doing it correctly, but the text is the same using raw commands and Loyverse, so I don't think Loyverse is converting to a bitmap and sending that data.

So my real question is: How do I send the correct character set for my printer? Maybe the character set is already correct, but the ASCII character for æøå/ÆØÅ are wrong?

EDIT: I have confirmed that something works with the `ESC XXXX` commands. If I do `27 97 2` followed by my "hello" sequence, the text is printed to the right (right aligned). So that definitely works.. I have tried probably all character sets thus far using `ESC R` and `ESC t` but none of them work :(

EDIT 2: I have now tested every single combination of `ESC R` and `ESC t`. I went through the entire list printing some Chinese characters, and every single line of 150+ I tried all returned the same Chinese character. So `ESC R` or `ESC t` is definitely not the command I should be using to change the charset.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate a [mcve]. What (exactly) is printed if you send string `æøå/ÆØÅ` after selecting _Denmark I_ by `ESC R 4`?

Comment: There seems to be a manual here, so why not check it out? [MPTII Programming Manual_Rev.1.2.zip](https://www.hprt.com/upload/files/MPTII%20Programming%20Manual_Rev.1.2.zip)

Comment: @kunif Sorry for the late reply. So I tried the following: `27 64 27 33 0 27 77 0 27 82 4 91 123 10 13` which resets the printer, sets the print mode, sets the character font, sets the character set to 'Denmark I', prints 'Ææ' and a new line. It prints `[{` instead, which tells me the character set is US, UK, Japanese, Korean, or Chinese. Definitely not Danish.

Comment: Perhaps the detailed model number differences or hardware mode settings limit the specifications for CJK countries. Please contact your reseller or vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Cancel chinese mode 0x1C + 0x2E
Some cheap aliexpress BT printers are default in Chinese mode, characters > 127